# git inside another git repo

Tags: git, github, sass

I am coding a template in html and sass
I'm having the following architecture

index.html
/scss
/assets

I accidentally created a git repo inside of scss then tryed deleting the .git file inside of scss directory and created a git repo in the root directory of the project and pushed to github but the directory scss is empty

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you delete the other files inside `/scss` too? Deleting a mistakenly made `.git` folder (not in the project root) should not delete anything else

Comment: No I didn't but when I see the repo on github I see an empty file called scss with an arrow icon on it

Answer (score 0):

When you do `git-init` on a new project git understands that the folder you are standing is going to be the master. After cloning or making a `git-commit` and `git-push`, then the rest of the documentation will be placed in that folder. Lets go a little back...

When you initialize a new project a hidden folder is created a `.git` folder. In order to erase a repository you would only need to erase that hidden folder and your project will be out of git, but ONLY that folder.

Any other deleted documents is either documentation or your project partially or completely.

I hope this was helpful.